# My webpage list using Laravel not showing data from database

Tags: php, database

Here is the web page:

[image]

Update data and ID is showing while other data such as customer name, phone, etc are not showing.

CustomersController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $customers = Customer::all();
    return view('customers.index', ['customers' => $customers]);
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Customers</h1>
    @if(count($customers)>0)
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Phone</th>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Updated on</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach($customers as $customer)
        
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{$customer->id}}</th>
                <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->phone}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->add}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->updated_at}}</td>
              </tr>                
        @endforeach
    @else
    @endif
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close `<table>` and `<tbody>`, and you placed `<tbody>` inside the loop (it should only appear once)

Try this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Customers</h1>
    @if(count($customers)>0)
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                <th scope="col">Updated on</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($customers as $customer)
              <tr>
                <td>{{$customer->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->phone}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->add}}</td>
                <td>{{$customer->updated_at}}</td>
              </tr>                
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @else
    @endif
@endsection
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code. but still not showing. But still same.

Comment: @soethein try now, you also used `<th>` instead of `<td>` inside `<tbody>`.

Comment: I have amended it. thanks. But still cannot see those data.

Comment: I wonder why id and date can see correctly and others just can't.

Comment: @soethein view page source in your browser, and show me the output

Comment: My guess is that they're actually empty in the database

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8fUcQCXzB9a9gy9D36nzFytylDVMFnB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry. I am new here and just now finding how to share page source with you. There is data in database for sure.

Comment: @soethein your link is not public

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8fUcQCXzB9a9gy9D36nzFytylDVMFnB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry about it. But now the problem is okay.

Comment: Thanks for your help and this is the working page source https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H-Gh69scdy-Qa6iXreSgVnjHbkWkCQNi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, I follow another youtube video about uploading excel to database. it helps and solved. the controller is passing as $data and edit blade i am using $customer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your table tag and `<tbody>` tag and `<tbody>` opening tag should be start before foreach loop.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8fUcQCXzB9a9gy9D36nzFytylDVMFnB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah. true. but after everything fixed also still not showing other data such as name and phone and email.